# FCM does not send notifications via console by user properties

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications via Firebase console by user properties.
Firebase is connected to my app correctly (I tried to send pushes via api request in postman).

In my activity, method `onCreate` I set properties:

```
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("companyName", "test");
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("userName", "test2"));
```

But I have noticed strange thing: when my app is closed, I obtain push notification by user property every time (with some delay, couple of minutes, but it is okay), but when app is opened, I get notification very-very rarely, probably one time out of ten.

And I can not understand what is the root of the problem. `FirebaseMessagingService` is working correctly (as I said, I tested via postman).

Can anyone help me please with it, some ideas what is wrong?